# Ruby Script - Surpress "Ask"

Tags: ruby, shell, scripting, rake

I am working with a 3rd party rake task that looks like this:

`abort("rake aborted!") if ask("Are you sure?", ['y', 'n']) == 'n'`

I am trying to write some additional rake tasks to automate this process.  Is there any way to surpress this question coming up? Or somehow feed it a `y` via the command line to make it happy?

I can edit the `Rakefile` but that is a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be happy to know that there's a unix command called `yes`. This will give you a constant stream of `y` which would be what you need.

Comment: Sometimes you just don't know the right question to ask! Thanks :)